Text aligns to the right when using line-clamp-1
With this Tailwind CSS code:
<div class="grid w-[500px] gap-4 grid-cols-2">
  <div class="space-y-2"><label class="text-sm font-medium leading-none peer-disabled:cursor-not-allowed peer-disabled:opacity-70" for=":re:-form-item">Country</label><button class="inline-flex items-center rounded-md text-sm font-medium ring-offset-background transition-colors focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-ring focus-visible:ring-offset-2 disabled:pointer-events-none disabled:opacity-50 border text-foreground hover:bg-subtle shadow-sm h-10 px-4 py-2 w-full justify-between whitespace-normal" role="combobox" type="button" aria-haspopup="dialog" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="radix-:rf:" data-state="closed"><span class="line-clamp-1">Congo, The Democratic Republic of the</span><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="lucide lucide-chevrons-up-down ml-2 h-4 w-4 shrink-0 opacity-50">
        <path d="m7 15 5 5 5-5"></path>
        <path d="m7 9 5-5 5 5"></path>
      </svg></button></div>
  <div class="space-y-2"><label class="text-sm font-medium leading-none peer-disabled:cursor-not-allowed peer-disabled:opacity-70" for=":rg:-form-item">Website</label><input class="flex h-10 shadow-sm xl:max-w-screen-sm rounded-md border border-input bg-transparent px-3 py-2 text-sm ring-offset-background file:border-0 file:bg-transparent file:text-sm file:font-medium placeholder:text-muted-foreground focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-ring focus-visible:ring-offset-2 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-50 w-full" id=":rg:-form-item" aria-describedby=":rg:-form-item-description" aria-invalid="false" type="text" value="https://www.tsmc.com/" name="website"></div>
</div>

When you use line-clamp-1, the text inside span aligns to the right:

If you remove line-clamp-1 and shorten the text, the text aligns to the left:

What could be the reason, and how to fix this inconsistency?
Tailwind Play

The default style of <button> has text-align: center. Try adding text-left to  to make it both align left.

@justanotherpeter And I think that can't be seen when line-clamp-1 isn't applied, because the span won't be wide enough so see the centering?

The parent <button> includes a class justify-between, which applies justify-content: space-between. This style will fill the flex container by inserting as much space between the children as possible.
This is desired behavior since you want the arrow icons to remain on the right side of the container. However, if you want the text to remain centered, you can instead add flex-grow: 1 to the <span>. This will grow the <span> to fill the space instead.
<span style="flex-grow:1">Congo,</span>

Updated Tailwind Play
On another note, adding flex-grow: 1 to the <span> makes the justify-between class superfluous and can be removed with no effects.
See here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/gZsweXRC74

No, I wanted the text to remain on the left, like it does when there is no line-clamp-1.
